# Contract-First Web Services using CXF , Spring and JAX-WS

Tags: web-services, spring, maven, jax-ws, cxf

I am currently looking at redeveloping a web service that is currently written in .Net.  I would like to port it across to Java using a CXF, Spring, Hibernate and Maven stack.

The WSDL for the service is already available and is well formed so I would like to reuse rather than redeveloping the interface.  This will also mean that the clients will not require significant changes in order to use the new service.

I would like to use a JAX-WS type approach to developing the web service, similar to the Java-first approach at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html.  The only difference being that I would like to follow a contract-first approach and ensure that the exact WSDL is used.

Has anyone attempted this before?  Are there any good guides online that I can refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am actually not seeing in your question what is stopping you from developing it with WSDL first approach.

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252249/cxf-jaxws-wsdl2java-bottomup-approach/14267539#14267539), for the tutorials you need.

Comment: +1 for the link to a complete sample. I noticed that your sample uses [maven-compiler-plugin](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/wsdl_first/pom.xml?view=markup) whereas [this tutorial](https://mvnwls.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/contract-first-cxf/) only uses `build-helper-maven-plugin`. What are is the main advantage of using one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

I guess its pretty straight forward (The WS stack part)
1.Create the Implementation stubs using WSDL (contract)
2.Create Client using WSDL
* implement methods using your own logic and syntax
both 1&2 is supported by CXF.

good guides [here](http://naveenbalani.com/index.php/2010/11/creating-contract-first-web-services-using-jax-ws-stack/)

and [here](http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2008/08/20/Defining+Contract+first+webservices+by+generating+wsdl+from+java)