# cxf-jaxws-wsdl2java-BottomUp approach

Tags: jax-ws, cxf, wsdl2java

I have a wsdl file with me now.
Using cxf 's 'wsdl2java' command,i convert wsdl to java classes.

How I can have my own implementation classes for the interfaces generated after wsdl to java conversion.?BAsically I need to do the following:
1.convert wsdl to java classes.
2.Write implementation classes for the classes generated.
3.Inject cxf into this.(cxf.xml and web.xml for apache CXF)
4.Package it to a war.

I hardly see a tutorial/help for this bottom up approach(ir,wsdl to java conversion mechanism)

Can someone give some pointers for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to create your own implementation of the web service you have to create a class(s) and implement the interface(s) generated from the `WSDL` file you have.

[Here is full example](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/wsdl_first/) of already created web service with Apache CXF and Maven using WSDL first approach. Just download sources, build it, deploy it, see how it works. It also contains all test with the client.

If you want to make only SOAP requests and see the response without java code you can use [SOAP UI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui/4.5.1/) tool for that.

**See also:**

1. http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-example-reportincident-part1.html